Salesforce Record Trigger Flow - Create test cases using 'View Tests'
We have a requirement to change the contact owner if it is created by a specific set of roles.
The Contact Owner should be changed to the Account Owner. I created the record trigger flow which is working as expected.
But, when I am creating 'View Test' cases it always fails.
In the Assertion I am giving that the Contact - Owner ID should be the Account Owner. And the test case always fails.

[![enter image description here[][3]3]4


I have a similar issue for a flow on Accounts. I get a similar error, with "Account.value". It smells like a bug and it gives the impression that Flow Tests are not a mature feature in Salesforce.
